# Dynamic page layout from 2D array using ng-repeat

Tags: css, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a server application which I am querying for a layout and get the following information - the coordinates of the top left corner of the object and it's width and height. The data is presented as a 2D array.

Using `ng-repeat` I have tried to iterate over the array as in the following [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/FgXsxXK1ezapI2vN4K8H?p=info).

This is the HTML template code:

```
<div ng-controller="PositionDemoCtrl" width="1000px" height="1000px">
  <div data-ng-repeat="option in options track by $index">
    <div width="{{option[0]}}" height="{{option[1]}}" top="{{option[2]}}px" left="{{option[3]}}px">&nbsp;</div.
  </div>
</div>
```

and my array in the controller:

```
 $scope.options = [[26,33,36,891],[25,29,72,341],
[17,20,145,0],[1,4,181,288],[17,25,363,0],[11,33,363,262],[30,54,399,944],[23,29,508,524],[17,16,690,236]];
```

Each sub-array represents the layout data in the order of width, height, top and left.

I find that all my divs are of equal height and the attributes though rendered in the HTML are not applied.

Am I missing something basic here or should I be trying a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

The `width`, `height`, `left` and `top` aren't meaningful HTML attributes. Although you can set them, they won't have any stylistic effect on the DOM element. Instead, you should set the corresponding CSS attributes. You can do that with the `ng-style` directive.

```
<div ng-style="{ 
    'width': option[0] + 'px',
    'height': option[1] + 'px',
    'top': option[2] + 'px',
    'left': option[3] + 'px' 
 }"></div>
```